# How to make "pin to start" for settings (wifi, bluetooth, etc.)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, wifi, tiles

How to make "pin to start" for settings (wifi, bluetooth, etc.).
like here: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quick-settings/2a2cbaa7-6d75-420c-ae14-2339618da43e

edit:

I have this code:

```
private void PinToStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Logo", UriKind.Relative),
                Title = AppResources.Social,
                Count = 0,
                BackTitle = "MyApp",
                BackContent = "",
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Logo.png", UriKind.Relative)
            };


            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
        }
```

need to when you click on a tile to display the configure Wifi

Comment: What have you tried? Much easier to help you if you say what you have already done.

Comment: I've added my code in header

Answer (score 0):

Just change the uri path to the settings page

eg

```
 ShellTile.Create(new Uri("ms-settings-bluetooth:", UriKind.AbsoluteorRelative), NewTileData);
```

Comment: error: An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.